# PyQt5Chart Series does not redraw when pen is updated only when OpenGL is enabled

Tags: python, qt, qtcharts

I've defined the following event filter for a custom legend Widget. Basically, when the mouse hovers over, I want the line to be made thicker.

This snippet works when OpenGL is disabled for all of the series. When OpenGL is enabled, however, it does not change the pen.

```
# self.series is a list
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(self.series[0].pen().color())
        pen.setWidth(6)
        pen.setCosmetic(False)
        list(map(lambda series: series.setPen(pen), self.series))
        return True
    elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(self.series[0].pen().color())
        pen.setWidth(3)
        pen.setCosmetic(False)
        list(map(lambda series: series.setPen(pen), self.series))
        return True
    return False
```

Is this a bug in Qt?

Comment: try with: `series.chart().update()`

Comment: @eyllanesc I will try this Monday, thank you. Still curious as to why i need to force the chart to update instead of it being automated.

Comment: mmm, it seems that it is a bug of Qt with opengl, I had the strategy of changing the size of the window, for there in some answer point it out.

Comment: Looks like i have a bug report to file then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around I've found is to toggle the visibility of each series after I change it's pen:

```
for series in self.series:
    series.setPen(pen)
    series.setVisible(False)
    series.setVisible(True))
```

Edit:

Thanks to @eyllanesc <strike>for this similar and more elegant solution:</strike>

`# Turns out this doesn't actually work for some reason`
    
<strike>`series.chart().update()`</strike>